# WebDriver Exception org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

When I try to use `WebDriver` to open a link with the local server, I get this error

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element:
>   phpmyamin opens

But when I try to use XPath for clicking on the link, the error takes off.
The most interesting thing is that the web site is all working fine, the error occurs only when it is running on the local server.
Just across the Selenium IDE it works fine

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://127.0.0.1/Tools/phpmyadmin/");
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

WebElement link = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@id='databaseList']/li/a"));
link.click();
```

Comment: try to run in debug mode. maybe 2 seconds not enough time

Comment: not sure can you plz share the html source code if possible as far as exception is concerned that means ur xpath is not correct.